# Is encoding random with module insecure?

Tags: random, encoding

The ID library [Nano ID](https://github.com/ai/nanoid#security) claims that modulo based encoding (e.g. Base64) would lead to uneven distribution in the output:

> **Uniformity.** `random % alphabet` is a popular mistake to make when coding an ID generator. The distribution will not be even; there will be a lower chance for some symbols to appear compared to others. So, it will reduce the number of tries when brute-forcing. Nano ID uses a better algorithm and is tested for uniformity.

This refers to something like the following [approach](https://www.slmanju.com/2021/07/basebase62-encoding-with-java.html) (example in Java):

```
  public String encode(long number) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(1);
    do {
      stringBuilder.insert(0, characters.charAt((int) (number % base)));
      number /= base;
    } while (number > 0);
    return stringBuilder.toString();
  }
```

What should be the "mistake" here? Why should the distribution not be even?

Comment: What are you planning to do with the encoding that it needs to be uniform?

Comment: Where does it talk about "encoding"?

Comment: The encoding is needed for output (e.g. logs) and for references like URLs. "Encoding" is not literally mentioned, but the approach is used to translate bits into characters, as you can see on the linked page where an alphabet is shown.

Comment: Why is it important that the encoding has uniform distribution of symbols?

Comment: You never answered my question. Why does the encoding need to be uniform? NanoID has nothing to do with encoding, nothing to do with translating binary data to an "alphabet" so it can be entered into logs or used in a URL.

Comment: You can't just remove Base64 but retain Base62 in your question. They are the same thing. An answer would have to apply to both. If there is confusion here, it would be your inclusion and citing of NanoID. And then you would have to explain how this would be a security question.

Answer (score 2):

Base64 is not a module operation but an encoding. This means that it does not selectively retain some information from the input but looses others as module does, but it is just a different representation of the input with full information kept. This means the cited argumentation in your question regarding module does not apply at all.

Specifically base64 is a mapping of 24 bit represented as 3 binary bytes (8 bit) to 24 bit represented as 4 text characters from a range of 64 different characters (6 bit). Each of the characters in is represented by a unique 6 bit sequence, which means if all of these 6 bit sequences are equally probable then each of the mapped characters will be equally probable too. Thus as long as the uniform random binary input is a multiple of 24 bit long, the output will also be uniformly random, only not binary but within the set of base64 characters.

But if the input is not a multiple of 24 bit long, then it will be padded to a multiple of 24 bit with 0, i.e. non-random data. Since this padded input is thus no longer uniformly random the encoding result will also not be uniformly random. And this is true even if one is ignoring any `=` characters, which are usually added to the end (i.e. can not occur anywhere else) to signal how many 0-bytes where padded.

The same is also true if the encoding is not base64 but some other similar encoding like base 32, base 8 (octal), base 10 (decimal) .... **As long as there is a need for some padding and the padding is not random this will introduce non-random data into the output**. This is also true for the code fragment you show, which implicitly has a padding with 0 (i.e. non-random). Note that when using base16 (hex) to encode full bytes no padding is ever needed, which means in this case the output is uniformly random if the input is.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I've rephrased my question to avoid confusion about Base64.

Comment: @deamon: I've rolled back your edit since the reference to base64 is essential to this answer, thus you basically changed an important aspect of what you ask. Significantly changing the question after you got answers is not a good style - ask a new question if you need instead. But I extended my answer for the more general case which matches your code.

Comment: Help me out, at what point would a non-uniform encoding method introduce a security issue?

Comment: @schroeder: Only if the encoded data themselves would be treated as random and not the underlying decoding data. I hope that nobody is actually doing this, but in a world where packing json as base64 into xml is considered normal I'm pretty sure that some insane software architects will actually do this.

Comment: That's as far as I was thinking, too. I can't see how the question itself, if asked properly, could be a security question at all.